# free marker template how to use for statement in double HashMap

Tags: java, freemarker

In free marker template i want to print HashMap in HashMap. Is this possible?

I try with

```
<#list capitalList?keys as key>
    ${key} = ${capitalList[key]}
</#list>
```

but this not printing HashMapin HashMap. How can i do this with free marker template. Exist foreach or for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nest `list` directive. A simple example:

```
<ul>
<#list hm2d?keys as hm2d_key>
    <#assign hm = hm2d[hm2d_key]>
    <li>${hm2d_key}:
        <ul>
        <#list hm?keys as key>
            <li>${key} = ${hm[key]}</li>
        </#list>
        </ul>
    </li>
</#list>
</ul>
```